# Got different zip structure from artifacts from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees, continuous-deployment

I have been using Cloudbees Jenkins as a service and I'm trying to setup my local Jenkins which I got different results from Cloudbees Jenkins.

If I use this curl command to get the latest successful artifact.

```
curl http://endpoint.cloudbees.com/job/jobname/20/artifact/project_name/build/distributions/*zip*/distributions.zip
```

I got a zip file with this structure.

- distributions/my_artifact.zip

But if I do the same command on my local Jenkins

```
curl http://localhost:8080/job/jobname/20/artifact/project_name/build/distributions/*zip*/distributions.zip
```

I just got

my_artifact.zip

which one is correct? And why they are different? I actually want my local Jenkins to produce the same results as as cloudbees.

I'm using Jenkins 1.534.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior on the CloudBees hosted Jenkins is the traditional and intended behavior. It looks like you found a bug in development builds of Jenkins, which I filed as [JENKINS-19947](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19947).

Comment: Wow Thanks I thought I use the latest version and I would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog

Read it.

```
* As of 1.532 download of artifact ZIPs was broken. (issue 19752)
```